# Ajax Dymamic Headers For Dynamic Class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making dynamic class name in php like that

```
<select name="kategori<?php echo $i; ?>" class="kategori<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

I'm getting $i from a loop , but i also want to

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var sayi = <?php echo $sayi; ?>

  $(".kategori").change(function()
  {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    var getSoru = "<?php echo TEMA_KLASOR."/doktorPaneli/inc/get_soru.php"; ?>";
    $.ajax
    ({
      type: "POST",
      url: getSoru,
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
        $(".soru").html(html);
      } 
    });
  });
```

Change this name $("kategori") dynamically as i did in php , something like $("kategori".$i) but I ve searched really a lot but didnt find any good resolution for this. If someone help, i would realy thankfull.

Comment: use event delegation for this use `.on()`